# Spinning the stick minigames - How to not destroy my palms?

Tags: mario-party

Mario Party 1 is infamous for it's spin the stick as fast as you can Minigames.

These minigames have a way to destroy the palm of your hands, and while playing a long game of mario party your hands can be at a point where you would probably have a bleeding wound in your hand.

Are there any tips and tricks to reduce the destruction of my hands while playing these games, without losing much performance? (because yes, I still want to win it)

Comment: Just be super pro and wear gloves while playing Mario Party like all the elite partiers do ;)

Comment: Alternatively, stop playing *Mario Party 1*?  I mean, it's almost 20 years old.  Surely there are other party games you can move on to which are more respectful of your hands...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wear gloves.
It's as simple as that, no really.

Just wear gloves, if you want to, wrap some bandages around your hand if you want to look like a Tekken character. Anything to cover up your hands should suffice.

If you don't want to do that I suggest you go the way of Tigress from Kung Fu Panda and hit trees all day long. If you want to you can wear some textured gloves to prevent your stick from slipping if that sometimes happens.
Otherwise, you can just wait for your hands to become calloused and it wont hurt anymore.

Comment: Fun fact, Nintendo actually mailed gloves out to owners of Mario Party 1 for free due to a lawsuit involving blistered palms